# In selenium, How to click on a required button depending on a condition when page contains multiple buttons of same structure

Tags: selenium

In the webpage, There are 25 messages which can have different status like Open, Assigned etc.

if the message is open status, i would like to click on "Assign" button for which id's are generated on the fly. How to identify and how to click in this case

Below is the code of one of the button present in the page

```
<a style="color:blue"
class="btn assign" 
data-userchannel="tw_757840449054711808~28353935~1000" 
data-elementid="tw_757840449054711808" 
id="tw_757840449054711808" 
title="Assign to user"
rel="act" 
href="/work/assignWork?messageId=tw_757840449054711808~SOLR&amp;dataSource=SOLR&amp;profileId=2305&amp;s360securetoken=mZ2GV6Tbfw7RubGR3Q05_dLM-XM" 
data-tooltip="Assign to user">
</a>
```

Static elements are class, title, tool tip. how to achieve this scenario.

Comment: what did you mean by "status", how did you learn about a message's status?

Comment: Use cssSelector as `a.btn.assign` to locate element..

Comment: Assign button appears only if the message (present in the web page being tested) status is open. So i want to click on the Assign button for an open status message. One page can contain 0-25 open messages, so there might be 25 assign buttons in a page

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't understand what are you saying?? If I understand correctly, If you want to click first assign button you need to pass index using cssSelector as `a.btn.assign:nth-child(1)`..

Comment: @Nagarjun so what was the result??

Comment: @SaurabhGaur that didn't work.

even tried these
`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@data-tooltip='Assign to user']"));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@data-tooltip,'Assign to user')]"));`

not sure why the question is voted down, couldn't ask one more question which is in the queue :)

Comment: @Nagarjun Why didn't work..?? is there any exception??

Comment: @SaurabhGaur yes. unable to locate element

`driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".btn.assign:nth-child(1)")).click();`

and

`driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.btn.assign:nth-child(1)")).click();`

same error

Comment: Did you tried using `WebDriverWait` to wait until element present in the `DOM` and also make sure this element is not inside any frame or iframe...

Comment: Where can we see the Open or Assigned status? I think you need to provide more of the surrounding HTML.

Comment: @SaurabhGaur used wait, but still not able to find the element.

Comment: @JeffC uploaded the page `https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4SgyzyvwKhiMElBdXFYS1pZLXM/view?usp=sharing`

due to the char limit here can't paste the whole page html. request you to check the page

Comment: @Nagarjun try as : `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.btn.assign")).click();`..it will click on first asign button..

Comment: @SaurabhGaur yes this works but there is one limitation. There are two functionalities in the page "Bulk assign and individual assign". In the DOM, bulk assign comes first, so it's being selected. i want to select the individual assign which comes after bulk assign. Basically second assign button.

Comment: @Nagarjun I got it after seeing your provided files..I provided it as an answer, try it and let me know..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all discussion, if you want to select first `assign` button you just try using `findElement`, it gives you first `assign` button :-

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.btn.assign")).click();
```

Now as you are saying There are two functionalities in the page Bulk `assign` and individual `assign` in the `DOM`, bulk `assign` comes first, so it's being selected but you want to select the individual assign which comes after bulk `assign`, then you should try using `findElements` to find all `assign` buttons and select anyone of these using index as below :-

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("a.btn.assign")).click();

if(elements.size() > 2) {
  //Now here you can pass index to get individual assign button
  elements.get(1).click(); //it will click second assign button and so on
}
```

Or you can use `xpath` to locate first individual `assign` button as below :-

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[@class = 'msgContent']/descendant::a[contains(@class,'btn assign')])[1]")).click();
```

Hope it helps..:)

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly your issue is with the Assign button not being located right? If that's the case then why not use XPath locator something like this: `.//a[@title='Assign to user']`. You can wrap this around WebDriverWait to wait till the element appears.

Comment: I want to click on the Assign button for an open status message. One page can contain 0-25 open messages, so there might be 25 assign buttons in a page. Will selenium randomly selects the assign button, i want to click on the first assign button in the loaded webpage

Comment: If you would analyse the DOM structure..there will always be some kind of association with the open message and corresponding assign button..then you need to tweak above XPath accordingly and click on it

Comment: tried these 

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@data-tooltip='Assign to user']")); driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@data-tooltip,'Assign to  user')]")); `

trying to analyse the dom

Comment: no no..you need to analyse open message and assign to user button